# a simple generalisation of the Applicative (Functor) type-class; pattern matching on constructors

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, functor

I've been trying to "learn me a Haskell" through the online book [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors).

The author describes the behaviour of Functors of the Applicative type as sort of having the ability to extract a function from one functor and mapping it over a second functor; this is through the <*> function declared for the Applicative type class:

```
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where  
    pure :: a -> f a  
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

As a simple example, the Maybe type is an instance of Applicative under the following implementation:

```
    instance Applicative Maybe where  
    pure = Just  
    Nothing <*> _ = Nothing  
    (Just f) <*> something = fmap f something
```

An example of the behaviour mentioned previously:

```
ghci> Just (*2) <*> Just 10         -- evaluates to Just 20
```

so the <*> operator "extracts" the (*2) function from the first operand and maps it over the second operand.

Now in Applicative types, both operands of <*> are of the same type, so I thought as an exercise why not try implementing a generalisation of this behaviour, where the two operands are Functors of different types, so I could evaluate something like this:

```
Just (2*) <*:*> [1,2,3,4]  -- should evaluate to [2,4,6,8]
```

So this is what I came up with:

```
import Control.Applicative

class (Applicative f, Functor g) => DApplicative f g where
    pure1 :: a -> f a
    pure1 = pure
    (<*:*>) :: f ( a -> b )  -> g a -> g b      -- referred below as (1)

instance DApplicative Maybe [] where    -- an "instance pair" of this class
    (Just func) <*:*> g = fmap func g

main = do putStrLn(show x)
    where x = Just (2*) <*:*> [1,2,3,4]  -- it works, x equals [2,4,6,8]
```

Now, although the above works, I'm wondering if we can do better; is it possible to give a default implementation for  <*:*> that can be applied to a variety of f & g pairs, in the declaration for DApplicative f g itself? And this leads me to the following question: Is there a way to pattern match on constructors across different data types?

I hope my questions make some sense and I'm not just spewing nonsense (if I am, please don't be too harsh; I'm just an FP beginner up way past his bedtime...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does make sense, but it ends up being not particularly useful in its current form.  The problem is exactly what you've noticed: there is no way to provide a default which does sensible things with different types, or to generally convert from `f` to `g`.  So you'd have a quadratic explosion in the number of instances you'd need to write.

You didn't finish the `DApplicative` instance.  Here's a full implementation for `Maybe` and `[]`:

```
instance DApplicative Maybe [] where    -- an "instance pair" of this class
    (Just func) <*:*> g = fmap func g
    Nothing     <*:*> g = []
```

This combines the behaviors of both `Maybe` and `[]`, because with `Just` it does what you expect, but with `Nothing` it returns nothing, an empty list.

So instead of writing `DApplicative` which takes two different types, what if you had a way of combining two applicatives `f` and `g` into a single type?  If you generalize this action, you could then use a standard `Applicative` with the new type.

This could be done with the standard formulation of Applicatives as

```
liftAp :: f (g (a -> b)) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)
liftAp l r = (<*>) <$> l <*> r
```

but instead let's change `Maybe`:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype MaybeT f a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: f (Maybe a) }

instance (Functor f) => Functor (MaybeT f) where
    fmap f (MaybeT m) = MaybeT ((fmap . fmap) f m)

instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (MaybeT f) where
    pure a = MaybeT (pure (pure a))
    (MaybeT f) <*> (MaybeT m) = MaybeT ( (<*>) <$> f <*> m)
```

Now you just need a way to convert something in the inner applicative, `f`, into the combined applicative `MaybeT f`:

```
lift :: (Functor f) => f a -> MaybeT f a
lift = MaybeT . fmap Just
```

This looks like a lot of boilerplate, but ghc can automatically derive nearly all of it.

Now you can easily use the combined functions:

```
*Main Control.Applicative> runMaybeT $ pure (*2) <*> lift [1,2,3,4]
[Just 2,Just 4,Just 6,Just 8]

*Main Control.Applicative> runMaybeT $ MaybeT (pure Nothing) <*> lift [1,2,3,4]
[Nothing,Nothing,Nothing,Nothing]
```

This behavior at Nothing may be surprising, but if you think of a list as representing indeterminism you can probably see how it could be useful.  If you wanted the dual behavior of returning either `Just [a]` or `Nothing`, you just need a transformed List `ListT Maybe a`.

This isn't quite the same as the instance I wrote for `DApplicative`.  The reason is because of the types.  `DApplicative` converts an `f` into a `g`.  That's only possible when you know the specific `f` and `g`.  To generalize it, the result needs to combine the behaviors of both `f` and `g` as this implementation does.

All of this works with Monads too.  Transformed types such as `MaybeT` are provided by monad transformer libraries such as [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl).

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive answer... I haven't gone through your code thoroughly yet, but I get the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DApplicative` instance for `Maybe` is not complete: What should happen if the first argument of `<*:*>` is `Nothing`?

The choice what to do for every combination isn't clear. For two lists `<*>` would generate all combinations: `[(+2),(+10)] <*> [3,4]` gives `[5,6,13,14]`. For two `ZipList`s you have a zip-like behaviour: `(ZipList [(+2),(+10)]) <*> (ZipList [3,4])` gives `[5,14]`. So you have to choose one of both possible behaviours for a `DApplicative` of a list and a `ZipList`, there is no "correct" version.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: Thanks! Corrected.